# Netlogo: How to iterate over agentset and set variable speed

Tags: loops, foreach, netlogo, agent, agentset

I am attempting to iterate over a set of turtles and assign each of them a different, random speed. When I attempt to use:`foreach turtles [ ... ]` I get an error message stating "cannot iterate over agentset". I know I can use `ask` for setting all turtles the same, but I want to have turtles moving at different speeds from one another.

Comment: Instead of cycles, you need to think this as a set operation. You ask the set to do something. Also, using cycles has a performance penalty on your models.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ask` can do this job just fine:

```
ask turtles [
  set speed random 10
]
```

this will give each turtle its own different, random speed.

Comment: just in case you want to have the turtle itself inside the block, use "self". [Link to the documentation](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/self.html).

Comment: This only works for random setting.. How do you set incrementing values to all turtles? eg. If I want 10 turtles with speeds from 1 to 10?

Comment: @freeworlder Not sure what you mean. Consider opening a new question and explaining what you mean in more detail

Comment: @SethTisue I meant 1,2,3,4... etc. I did it using a while loop.

Comment: @ColinR.Turner, can you post your ```while``` loop solution? I came across this post and would find it useful in what I'm working on! :)